# assert_called_once_with() with datetime.now() in the call parameter?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have the following test code to test `Decorator`.

```
@mock.patch('a.b.c.KafkaProducer')
def test_1(self, mocked):
    decorator = Decorator(....)

    @decorator()
    def test():
        return 42
    test()

    start_time = ???
    v = {'type': 'batch', 'start_time': start_time.isoformat()}
    mocked.return_value.send.assert_called_once_with(value=v)
```

However, the test always fail because `Decorator` calls mocked with dictionary parameter with property of `start_time` assigned to `datetime.now()`. Is it a way to compare everything except `start_time`? Or any other way to test the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two practical approaches:

**freeze time** using https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/

```py
import datetime
from freezegun import freeze_time
from unittest.mock import patch
import my_library


NOT_NOW = datetime.datetime.now()


@freeze_time("2020-01-01")
@patch("my_library.helper")
def test_foo(_helper):
    my_library.under_test(NOT_NOW)
    # kinda auto-magic
    _helper.assert_called_once_with(datetime.datetime.now())
    # or more explicitly
    _helper.assert_called_once_with(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1))
```

or, **evaluate arguments manually**

```py
@patch("my_library.helper", return_value=42)
def test_bar(_helper):
    my_library.under_test(NOT_NOW)
    assert _helper.call_count == 1
    assert _helper.call_args[0][0]
    assert _helper.call_args[0][0] != NOT_NOW
```